# C# initializing List Collection

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I have always initialized a collection as such:-

```
List<Type> name = new List<Type>();
```

But today I saw something like this:-

```
var variablename = new sMonth{
    x = foo;
    name = new List<Type>()
};
```

Is that even possible? and what is the difference between the two ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your second snippet is an example of [object initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

Assuming your `sMonth` object contains a property of type `List<Type>`, you can initialize the object at the point you create the outer object:

```
var variablename = new sMonth{
    x = foo,
    name = new List<Type>()
};
```

Note the comma between items.

Additionally, since you're not assigning anything to `name` you could use the `sMonth` constructor to initialize the collection for you:

```
public sMonth()
{
    name = new List<Type>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense now.

Comment: Could I request you to look at a different piece of code and get your opinion ?

Comment: @Philo if it's related to this question, just edit your original question. Otherwise, best to open a new question and ask there.